# Are the directions NE, NW, SE and SW ever read the Chinese way?

Tags: words

In Chinese the order is reversed such that:

NE 东北

NW 西北

SE 东南

SW 西南

My textbook says the Japanese order is the same as English which surprised me.

Was it or is it ever said using the Chinese order?